# grant remote access permission to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, linux, nginx

Hello I am on a Centos VPS with nginx + mysql + php-fpm installed. I am trying to allow remote access to a database on this machine from another of my VPS.

I tried out the following steps.

- Modified the `/etc/my.cnf` file and then within the [mysqld] block added the lines `bind-address = *`
- Saved and restarted the mysql service using the command `/etc/init.d/mysqld restart`
- Logged into mysql
- Typed the `use social` command and tried to run the command `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO root@'1.2.3.4' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';` Where 1.2.3.4 is the IP of the VPS I want to remote access the social database from.

The error is get is

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

On digging up a bit more I have found out that if I use the command

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON dbname TO root@'1.2.3.4' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';
```

where **dbname** is the name of the database I want to operate upon, then it works and after flushing the privileges I can see  that the new mysql.user table has the new user grants in it. But even then If I try to connect to them remotely I get a blank page. With no exception whatsoever. 
Here is a copy of the php file I am using to connect to this database.

```
<?php

$conn = @mysql_connect('1.2.3.4','root','pass');
if (!$conn) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
try{
    mysql_select_db('dbname', $conn);   
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    echo $error = "An error has occured ".$e->getMessage()." (Code: ".$e->getCode()." )";
    echo $error;
}
try{
$sql    = "SELECT * FROM bla_user";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
echo $count;
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    echo $error = "An error has occured ".$e->getMessage()." (Code: ".$e->getCode()." )";
    echo $error;
}
?>
```

I have changed the password and database name in here. 
The files are currently hosted both on the main VPS and the one I am trying to access it from and can be viewed at http://www.jukpac.com/test.php and http://www.techbreeze.in/test.php

Can someone let me know why I am encountering this error when I can log in and create users even operate on the database using the same username, root and the same password even after this error!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after runnig this command

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON dbname TO root@'1.2.3.4' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';
```

run this command also

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

for more [refer to the mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/privilege-changes.html)

Comment: I have already done that but to no use, when i try to login remotely and try and run the select command it says that the user doesn't have permission to run select. But I have already run the grant all privileges command !!

Comment: ok than read the documentation and grant PRIVILEGES to particular user, on tables and on columns also :)

Comment: I have managed to fixed it, the thing going wrong was the command `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON dbname TO root@'1.2.3.4' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';` This was granting privileges to only the table `dbname.dbname` The correct one would be `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON dbname.* TO root@'1.2.3.4' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';`

Comment: sorry dear than i am unable to solve this...